# How to result "count" from this array using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, get

I want result to be

- label_id 29 and content_text 19 = 1
- label_id 29 and content_text 27 = 1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 70
            [content_id] => 354
            [label_id] => 28
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => product
            [content_text] => 14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 70
            [content_id] => 355
            [label_id] => 29
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => location
            [content_text] => 26
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 70
            [content_id] => 356
            [label_id] => 30
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => business
            [content_text] => 35
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 70
            [content_id] => 362
            [label_id] => 35
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => visibility
            [content_text] => 41
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 71
            [content_id] => 365
            [label_id] => 28
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => product
            [content_text] => 14
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 71
            [content_id] => 366
            [label_id] => 29
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => location
            [content_text] => 27
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 71
            [content_id] => 367
            [label_id] => 30
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => business
            [content_text] => 35
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 71
            [content_id] => 373
            [label_id] => 35
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => visibility
            [content_text] => 42
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 74
            [content_id] => 389
            [label_id] => 28
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => product
            [content_text] => 14
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 74
            [content_id] => 390
            [label_id] => 29
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => location
            [content_text] => 21
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 74
            [content_id] => 391
            [label_id] => 30
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => business
            [content_text] => 35
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 74
            [content_id] => 397
            [label_id] => 35
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => visibility
            [content_text] => 42
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 85
            [content_id] => 420
            [label_id] => 28
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => product
            [content_text] => 14
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 85
            [content_id] => 421
            [label_id] => 29
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => location
            [content_text] => 18
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 85
            [content_id] => 422
            [label_id] => 30
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => business
            [content_text] => 35
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 85
            [content_id] => 428
            [label_id] => 35
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => visibility
            [content_text] => 42
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 136
            [content_id] => 531
            [label_id] => 28
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => product
            [content_text] => 14
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 136
            [content_id] => 532
            [label_id] => 29
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => location
            [content_text] => 27
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 136
            [content_id] => 533
            [label_id] => 30
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => business
            [content_text] => 35
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 136
            [content_id] => 539
            [label_id] => 35
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => visibility
            [content_text] => 42
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 56
            [content_id] => 258
            [label_id] => 28
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => product
            [content_text] => 14
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 56
            [content_id] => 259
            [label_id] => 29
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => location
            [content_text] => 24
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 56
            [content_id] => 261
            [label_id] => 30
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => business
            [content_text] => 35
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 56
            [content_id] => 267
            [label_id] => 35
            [type_id] => 6
            [label_name] => visibility
            [content_text] => 41
        )

)
```

Comment: I hope some one help me.

Comment: Your question is unclear .Include more information that's why we can help you

Comment: Do you want to get count of items with `label_id` 29 ` and content_text` 19?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: $filter =('product','location','business');

$count = 0;
                         foreach ( $CheckIn as $child ){
                              if ( $child['content_text'] == $opt['options_id']  && $child['label_id'] == $label['label_id'] && !in_array($label['label_name'], $filter, TRUE)){
                                  $count++;
                              }
                          }

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code.

```
$query="select * From user";
$queryResult = $db->query($query);
$result = $queryResult->fetch();
echo $result['count'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function `echo count( $arrayResult)`;
but your question is not clear.....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a count of unique label_id & context_text field, Then do rekey of the input array with a which-ever field you want then just use count function for taking count.

Am not clear about your question, but I thought might be you want output like this.

Comment: $count = 0;
                          foreach ( $CheckIn as $child ){
                              if ( $child['content_text'] == $opt['options_id']  && $child['label_id'] == $label['label_id'] && !in_array($label['label_name'], $filter, TRUE)){
                                  $count++;
                              }
                          }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count array element which has key/s with a specific value, use the following code.

```
<?php

// By Moustafa Elkady

function count_by_key_value($arr,$search)
{
    $count = 0;

    foreach ($arr as $array_elements) {
        $matched = 0;
        foreach ($search as $search_key => $search_value) {
            if (isset($array_elements[$search_key]) && $array_elements[$search_key] == $search_value) {
                $matched++;
            }
        }

        if ($matched == count($search)) {
            $count++;
        }

    }

    return $count;
}


$arr = [

    [
        'label_id' => 29,
        'content_text' => 19
    ],

    [
        'label_id' => 29,
        'content_text' => 19
    ],

    [
        'label_id' => 2,
        'content_text' => 19
    ],

];

var_dump(count_by_key_value($arr,['label_id' => 2,'content_text' => 19]));
```